# Is there a record of George McClellan confessing timidity?

Tags: american-civil-war

In a college history class I remember my professor presenting a letter or diary entry by George McClellan in which he confessed his timidity and expressing bewilderment at the boldness and initiative of the confederate generals (or was it the other union generals?). I vaguely recall how he expressed his inability to comprehend how the generals are able to act so decisively based on imperfect information, leaving their flanks exposed, and without sufficient planning for contingencies, etc.

Does this ring a bell to anyone? If so, can you provide a reference to the source?